# How to take the seed for a random generator from the clock, programming in assembler

Tags: assembly, random

Compiler, TASM 5

Architecture x86.

For a random number generator algorithm, take tha clock as the seed.

---

I found that solution:

```
AcquireSeed PROC

    PUSH AX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH DX

    MOV Ah, 00h ; Int
    INT 1AH     ; return the clock in CX:DX

    MOV seed, DL ; save the less significant byte of the clock at seed (declared at .data)

    POP DX
    POP CX
    POP DX

AcquireSeed endp
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Don't leave these kinds of sparse, vague questions.

Comment: What architecture, x86?  PowerPC?  ARM?

Comment: @Rich: 'random algorithm'=random number generator, 'feed'=seed.

Comment: @Mike F, Thanks! English isn't my native language... as you can see.

Comment: @TCJ: So is RDTSC what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by the question, but are you possibly looking for [RDTSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDTSC)?

If so, it's not directly supported by TASM but you can insert the opcode for it with

```
db 0Fh, 31h
```